# PIC16F1823 baud rate generator registers fail to be set

Tags: pic, uart, mplab, baud-rate

I have encountered a strange problem: I am trying to simply set UART baud rate on my PIC16F1823 in MPLABX just by writing some values to `SPBRGH` and `SPBRGL`. After seeing that UART communication doesn't really work, I checked in the debugger, that the registers don't change values after writing to them (they stay at 152 and 48 correspondingly). I experimented a lot and found out, that what **actually GETS set is `SP1BRGH` and `SP1BRGL`** registers, although the naming is wrong - **that pic is equipped in only one UART, besides the naming in datasheet is `SPBRGH` and `SPBRGL`**. The other symptom is that in the *watch* window, the *diamond* icon next to the `SPBRG*` variables has a *P* inside, while next to `SP1BRG*` no - I was unable to find the meaning of `P` though. Do you think this is some kind of a bug? The code is so simply, that I cannot get myself thinking otherwise. If so, what would be the mysterious *152* and *48* values then?

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, much time lost (this kind of problem has to get some name, I vote for SMMTL). I haven't noticed that used by me pins on this specific PIC have settable alternate function, and what is more, the default function assignment was not the one that I used. I incorrectly estimated the cause and

```
APFCONbits.RXDTSEL = 1; //RA1
APFCONbits.TXCKSEL = 1; //RA0
```

solved the problem. **ALTHOUGH** this still doesn't solve the mistery of unchangeable `SPBRGH` and `SPBRGL` in the debugger and the *P* icon, but this is a topic for other question.

Comment: Could the issue with setting the baud rate generator be that the UART was enabled at the time? Changing the baud rate while the UART is enabled could cause problems, and may not be possible with some hardware.

Comment: In PICs case this shouldn't be a problem, at most you'll loose data during reception, but that's inevitable: _Writing a new value to the SPBRGH, SPBRGL register pair causes the BRG timer to be reset (or cleared). This ensures that the BRG does not wait for a timer overflow before outputting the new baud rate._ - _EUSART Baud Rate Generator chapter._ But anyway it was disabled :)